# Forward traffic from IP accessing specific port to other port

Tags: iptables

## Sidenote

This question is nearly the same to this question: [Forward all traffic on a specific port depending on the domain to another port](https://serverfault.com/questions/366565/) but I have a totally different aim with my one.*

## Schematic

I want to have an **IPTABLE** rule for this schematic:
[*click to open image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n1sZ.png).

### Description of Image

- Traffic from 123.123.123.***1*** which accesses 123.123.123.3:80 is *NOT* going to be forwarded.
- Traffic from 123.123.123.***2*** which accesses 123.123.123.3:80 *IS* going to be forwarded to 123.123.123.3:8080

---

I already went through http://www.howtoforge.com/nat_iptables
and other pages about NAT and stuff but I couldn't manage to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the source IP address as an argument and take the desired action accordingly:

```
# Reject forwards from 123.123.123.1 to 123.123.123.3 on port 80 TCP
iptables -A FORWARD -s 123.123.123.1 -d 123.123.123.3 -p TCP --dport 80 -j REJECT

# But accept forwards from 123.123.123.2 to 123.123.123.3 to port to TCP
iptables -A FORWARD -s 123.123.123.2 -d 123.123.123.3 -p TCP --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```